# Serialize nested JSON string using a datatable

Tags: json, vb.net, dataset

I have this JSON string:

```
{
  "DataflowID": 1234,
  "Data": [    
    {
      "Key": "TIMESTAMP",
      "Value": "2019/11/11 07:00:00"
    },
    {
      "Key": "test1",
      "Value": "5.819720684"
    },
    {
      "Key": "test2",
      "Value": "12.47921946"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I am using the below code to get the data from the database and make the JSON string:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

        Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet("dataSet")
        dataSet.[Namespace] = "NetFrameWork"
        Dim jsonTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim keyColumn As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Key")
        Dim valueColumn As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Value")
        jsonTable.Columns.Add(keyColumn)
        jsonTable.Columns.Add(valueColumn)
        dataSet.Tables.Add(jsonTable)

        jsonTable.TableName = "Data"

        For m = 1 To g
            Dim dataRow2 As DataRow = jsonTable.NewRow
            dataRow2("Key") = "Timestamp"
            dataRow2("Value") = testTimestamp(m)
            jsonTable.Rows.Add(dataRow2)

            For k = 1 To tagsCounter
                Dim dataRow1 As DataRow = jsonTable.NewRow
                dataRow1("Key") = testName(k)
                dataRow1("Value") = testValue(m, k)
                jsonTable.Rows.Add(dataRow1)
            Next k
        Next m
```

But I cannot make the property dataFlowID .

Comment: So, you are trying to make a json string that you wrote in the beginning? There are simpler ways then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build a class to represent the JSON and fill it in. For example:

```
Public Class JsonHolder
    Public DataflowId As Integer
    Public Data As DataTable
End Class
```

It looks like you already have the `Data` part sorted, so you just need to put that into a new instance of this holder class along with the `DataflowId`:

```
Dim holder = New JsonHolder With {
    .DataflowId = 1234,
    .Data = jsonTable
}
```

Then use Newtonsoft to serialise to JSON:

```
Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(holder, Formatting.Indented)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the code, but now the text though includes DataflowId the Data is not filled with data. This is the result: {"DataflowId":1234,"Data":[]}

Comment: Does your code produce `jsonTable` correctly? The problem you are describing suggests that your data table is empty.

Comment: When I use these lines of code I get the datatable exactly the way I want it.   dataSet.AcceptChanges()
  Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet, Formatting.Indented)

Comment: I have tried it this already, but still I don't have the proper result.

Comment: Yep - you need to use jsonTable rather than the DataSet (have edited the answer back to the original) otherwise you get the `Data` header twice. I have the code above working in a test project and the output exactly matches your desired JSON.

Comment: Still nothing. The jsonTable seems to be empty.

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed the code to work and I got the result that I want.

Comment: OK good news. If the answer helped then you can [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).